# Custom document extractor Batch Processing Request

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

How to send batch processing request using Custom document extractor?

I tried using Jupyter Notebook by creating a cluster but the Python code didn't work. It's not showing any output whenever I run the code.

Comment: Could you put your code example in the post?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this documentation for how to [send a batch processing request](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#batch-process) for any processor type and get the response.

> Batch (asynchronous) requests let you send multiple documents in a single
> request. The input files must be stored in Google Cloud Storage. Document AI responds with an [`operation`](https://cloud.google.com//document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.operations)
> that you can poll for the status of the request. When this operation finishes,
> it contains a [`BatchProcessMetadata`](https://cloud.google.com//document-ai/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/BatchProcessMetadata)
> that points to the Google Cloud Storage bucket where the processed results are
> stored.
>
> If the input files you want to access are in a bucket in another project, you must provide access to that bucket before you can access the files. See [Cross-Project file access setup](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/cross-project-setup).

You can also refer to this codelab for more instructions.

https://goo.gle/3OVnmnO